# System information disabled due to load higher than 4.0 but it ain't higher than 4.0

Tags: top

On one of my Raspberry PI's I got the following warning after login:
System information disabled due to load higher than 4.0

But top doesn't reflect that (see screenshot), am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to Ask Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question accordingly. There is a site on Stack Exchange dedicated to [questions about Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It looks like you have a raspberry pi 4 with 8G of RAM, and you are running Ubuntu 20.04 or similar. Please try disabling `hdmi_enable_4kp60=1` in `boot/config.txt` it may help with CPU usage(s) if you don't use a 4k monitor.

Comment: @24601 it works such way that the Raspberry SE likes to deal with electric motors connected to their GPIO port, maybe fixing their micro-HDMI issues, but they refuse to deal with questions that are too "Linuxy". They say the operating system's Linuxy problems should be solved on the other Linuxy SE sites. They have thrown out mine about generating thumbnails on — wait for it — Raspberry Pi OS (which is Debian based); I had to [ask it again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/635421/448600) on unix.SE; of course noone answered there either :) This is an unlucky area; no-one seems to want it. :(

Comment: @24601 I'm running Ubuntu on it, hence I posted the question on askubuntu ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if the system is particularly busy at the moment you try to connect.

It's not Pi-specific, I've seen it on low-resource servers of several varieties.

One example where I see this more often: A slightly-too-early connection after a boot. The system is still working hard for a few more seconds to finish the boot jobs. A second connection a few seconds later, after the system has settled, is normal.

It's not just boot. If the system CPUs are simply busy running Minecraft Servers or ROS or hourly cronjobs or any other intensive task at the moment you coincidentally connect, you will get that message.